# How to make case insensitive on accepting file formats in DropZone Js

Tags: dropzone.js, case-sensitive, file-format

currently, DropZone Js accepting file formats based on case sensitive but would like to make it as case insensitive.

Like I have mentioned ".jpg" in acceptedFile formats. it should work for ".JPG"
also.

Please share your ideas on it.

Answer (score 0):

Find those lines in dropzone source and add toLowerCase

```
    validType = validType.trim().toLowerCase();
if (validType.charAt(0) === ".") {
  if (file.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(validType, file.name.length - validType.length) !== -1) {
    return true;
  }
```